# adobe air(xml request)

Tags: air, adobe

what actually local path adobe air accept ?
i try xml http request using  file:///c:/folder/file.txt .It work on Chrome but when testing on air it fail to retrieve the text file?I thought adobe air is webkit engine so testing should be the same.I'm using adobe air 1.5

Comment: I tried XMLHttpRequest for reading local file.Chrome can output the file while adobe air  cannot see the file.